# ASP.Net HttpCookie Expiration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, httpcookie

If you set a cookie's expiration to DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), when would it expire? It shows that the expiration is yesterday. Here is the code:

```
var rememberMeCookie = new HttpCookie("remember_me");
rememberMeCookie.Expires =  DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: need the code u used..

Comment: In this case the cookie is already expired. what is the point of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no HTTP Header to delete the cookie, when you click "Logout", this is a trick to confuse browser with previous expiration date, so browser will immediately delete cookie from its store.

Answer (score 0):

This question is like you bought a milk on 11/09/2015 but expired on 10/09/2015, then you ask:" should i drink it?" Of cause not! because expired is 'YESTERDAY' like you said.

you cannot get anything from a expired cookie.

Comment: this is a trick to force browser to delete cookie immediately.